# Finding the Line Count of a Textblock in windows phone 7 & 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using a TextBlock in windows phone.

I am binding a string which can be of any length. I want to show only two lines if the string length is more then two lines and i want show the "..." at the end of the second line.

Here i can't use Length because ex: 'W' will take up more space but thinner characters like 'I' may not even reach the second line. So i can't use the Length here.

I have seen the TextTrimming="WordEllipsis", but it shows the ellipsis after a word. If last word of second line is too big then last word will be removed.

**so please tell me how can i find the line count of a Textblock.**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis".

Either do it yourself: http://igrali.com/2013/03/31/character-ellipsis-trimming-in-windows-store-apps/

Or wait some weeks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming.aspx

Comment: This is not a Windows 8 (Windows Store) question.

Comment: Ouch. Right. So it doesn't make sense to wait. However overriding MeasureOverride of a content control should work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in windows phone both textwrappin&texttriming doesn't working at a time,and so here I am using textblock loaded event,and in c#  3 text blocks are taken to meet your requirement.

In your xaml,

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text=""  Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  MaxHeight="60" Foreground="#F97E7F81"  FontFamily="Segoe WP"  FontSize="18" Width="430" FontWeight="Bold" Loaded="desc" />
```

In c#,

private void desc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
        TextBlock tb1=new TextBlock();
        tb1.Text = tb.Text;
        tb1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb1.Width = 435;
        tb1.Height = 75;
        TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
        tb2.Text = tb1.Text;
        tb2.Height = 75;
        tb2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb2.Width = 435;
        tb.Text = tb2.Text;
        tb.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    }
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without setting ellipsis would be rendering the text (or a copy of the textblock) incrementally in another context inside a value converter, finding the correct width/height etc. that fits into your available area, and return that text (or like 2-3 characters less and an extra ellipsis by yourself).

I definitely do *not* recommend this approach at all, and this is definitely not an optimum way of doing this, but if no other answer suits, this should work for the simple cases.